# When does isModified() return true in mongoose? I am looking for a brief explanation

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I want to know when `(user.isModified('password')` is true in the code below? Its a bit confusing, as for the firsttime the password is not changing so `isModified` should return false. right?

```
userSchema.pre('save', function(next){
var user = this;
if (user.isModified('password')){
    bcrypt.genSalt(saltRounds, function(err, salt) {
        if(err) return next(err);
        bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
            if(err) return next(err);
            user.password = hash;
            next();
        });
    });
}else{
    next();
}});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you change the value of the certain field, the value of isModified will get changed. So `user.isModified('password')` will be true whenever `'password'` gets modified. In the first case, the password value initially would have been empty or null, so it will return `true` in that case as well.